# Show data of DVD that has not been loaned for last 31 days (a month)

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I want to display a list of all DVD titles in the shop where no copy of the title has been loaned in the last 31 days (where `DateOut >= Current_date – 31`) in the GridView in Visual Studio Asp. I've got a SQL query below but I have no idea what to put in **`WHERE`** clause:

```
SELECT DVDTitle.DVDNumber, DVDTitle.DVDTitle
  FROM DVDTitle
  INNER JOIN DVDCopy
    ON DVDTitle.DVDNumber = DVDCopy.DVDNumber
  INNER JOIN Loan
    ON DVDCopy.CopyNumber = Loan.CopyNumber
  WHERE <what goes here?>
  ORDER BY DVDTitle.DVDNumber;
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: I'm using T-SQL in Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I think of using `NOT EXISTS` for this type of query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM DVDTitle t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM DVDCopy c JOIN
                       DVDLoan l
                       ON c.CopyNumber = l.CopyNumber
                  WHERE t.DVDNumber = c.DVDNumber AND
                        l.DateOut >= DATEADD(day, -31, GETDATE())
                 );
```

In any case, the date arithmetic in the final condition varies much among databases.  This is (rather arbitrarily) using SQL Server date functions.  The ANSI standard would be more like `l.DateOut >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '31 DAY'`.

Answer (score 0):

Use DATEDIFF() and GETDATE()

DATEDIFF: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

GETDATE: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Loan.DateOut, GETDATE()) >= 31
```

Comment: That won't be optimal since SQL Server will have to evaluate that datediff function for every row. Better to do something like `where Loan.DateOut <= DATEADD(day, -31, getdate())` as the optimizer is smart enough to realize that the right side of that inequality is a static value and will calculate it only once.